# Use leidenalg and igraph to find cluster and then output gml file

Tags: python, igraph, gml

```
import leidenalg as la

import igraph as ig

G = ig.Graph.Famous('Zachary')

partition = la.find_partition(G, la.ModularityVertexPartition)

ig.plot(partition,vertex_size = 30)

ig.save(G,'ttt.gml')
```

Everything works fine, however ig.save does not contain cluster information, just nodes and edges.
Need to add Cluster information to nodes in ttt.gml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph itself doesn't contain any information of the partition. You should first add this information to the graph before saving it by doing `G.vs['cluster'] = partition.membership`.

Comment: Thanks, this just worked! Loaded gml file into Gephi and verified that it worked.

Comment: Great, good to hear. Do note that the Leiden algorithm is also available as a plugin to Gephi, so if that is all that you do in `igraph`, you can also just do that in Gephi itself.